# Проблема с экспортом из DLL в vb.net

Tags: c#, c++, dll, vb.net, lua

Нужна помощь профи , проблема в следующе у меня в DLL организовано подключение к Lua через static struct luaL_reg ls_lib[] , и экспорт в vb.net через DllImport\DllExport. С Lua скриптом все работает отлично , а вот экспорт в vb.net не происходит и выдает ошибку "Не удается загрузить DLL "dllTest.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" Если я удалю регистрацию для Lua "static struct luaL_reg ls_lib[]" экспорит в vb.net происходит отлично но тогда не работает dll с lua. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить данную проблему . Задача такая , что dll должна принимать строку из vb.net и отпровлять её в QLua ответ с скрипта отправлять обратно в vb.net

Код на C++

```
#define EXPORTING_DLL
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using std::string;
//=== Необходимые для Lua константы ============================================================================//


#define LUA_LIB
#define LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL

//=== Заголовочные файлы LUA ===================================================================================//
extern "C" {
#include "Lua\lauxlib.h"
#include "Lua\lua.h"
}

//=== Стандартная точка входа для DLL ==========================================================================//
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
   case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
   case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
   case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
   case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
   break;
}
  return TRUE;
}

extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) const char* GetString(char* s);
}


const char* GetString(char* s)
{      

   string workStr(s);      
   int lenStr = workStr.length() + 1;
   char* answer = new char[lenStr];
   const char * constAnswer = new char[lenStr];
   strcpy(answer, workStr.c_str());
   constAnswer = answer;
   return (constAnswer);
}


//=== Регистрация реализованных в dll функций, чтобы они стали "видимы" для Lua ================================//
static struct luaL_reg ls_lib[] = {
  { "CheckGotPARAMS", forLua_CheckGotPARAMS },
  { NULL, NULL }
};

//=== Регистрация названия библиотеки, видимого в скрипте Lua ==================================================//
extern "C" LUALIB_API int luaopen_Connector(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_openlib(L, "Connector", ls_lib, 0);
  return 0;
};
```

Код на vb.net

Public Shared Function GetString(ByVal s As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    Private ptr

```
Public Function GetString_(ByVal s As String) As String
    ptr = GetString(s)
    Dim answerStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr)

    'TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + 1
    Return answerStr
End Function
```

Comment: А что, вообще, такое dllTest.dll?

Answer (score 0):

Нашол решение своей проблемы . НА другом форуме добрый человек подсказал решение , нужно было заменить саму библиотеку Lua . и все заработало. https://www.cyberforum.ru/lua/thread2590942.html#post14291241